# Adopt IP of network connecting to without routing everything through the VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ip

Is it possible with OpenVPN to adopt the IP of the network I'm connecting to, so to the outside it looks like I have the same IP instead of my own local one?

This could work when I route everything through the vpn with `redirect-gateway def1` but is there a way without doing that? It really slows down speed overall and any other benefits of this aren't needed.

I just want the same IP for "whitelist reasons".

Current client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
nobind
pull
resolv-retry infinite
key-direction 1
remote here_is_our_ip
script-security 2
comp-lzo
reneg-sec 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
```

Some more details to explain my situation:

I have set up a OpenVPN server in our office network where we have a static IP. I want that co-workers that connect to our VPN have the same static IP like we have in the office instead their own dynamic IP that gets renewed from time to time by their ISP.
The overall use for this is to whitelist our static IP on our website for matomo statistics. So when a co-worker in the home office accesses our website it's not counted in our statistics.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Please elaborate more. But if I understand you correct, you just need to use a global IP address. This is globally unique and doesn't need to be routed. In practice you need to use an IPv6 address.

Comment: @paladin Thanks, I've added some details.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could set a source IP on a packet that goes out. **But in practice not.**

The Users own equipment would need to set this source IP, but most ISPs does not allow for spoofing a IP that "don't belong to you (the user)".

Even if you could, the traffic would still come "back in" thru the office, and that would need to be routed back to the correct client, with NAT this requires connection tracking, and that did not happen on the way out so there is no way to know which client it should go to.

If every VPN client got their own public IP this might be possible, but again requires that the users own ISP would allow spoofing the IP (should not be allowed)

What you could do is to only route traffic over the VPN with destinations to the specific services that needs whitelisting, or maybe even only the authenticating service.

Comment: Thank you very much for your evaluation. Only routing specific services through the VPN is a good idea. I will look into that. But do you know if I can "only" route for example chrome through it (so whole programs), or can I specify it to only route when visiting one specific website (which I know the IP of)

Comment: "Routing an application" is more of a client OS issue, but for the purpose of chrome or web browsers, consider looking into using a proxy instead. If client is Windows there is also wpad scripts that can be used to redirect over proxy or direct depending on destination hostname.